# Rails can't find ApplicationRecord after upgrade to Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[Per the upgrade notes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html), I've added the `app/models/application_record.rb` file with the following content:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

But when I try to run `bin/rails s`, I see the following error:

```
active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:21:in `method_missing': undefined local variable or method `  self' for ApplicationRecord(Table doesn't exist):Class (NameError)
```

It seems as if rails can't find the `application_record.rb` file, but I've reload spring, and also tried running `rails s` (without the bin). But always the same error.

I'm on a Mac, running ruby 2.3.

Here's my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '5.0.0'
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

#translations
gem 'rails-i18n'
gem 'i18n-active_record',
  :git => 'git://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n-active_record.git',
  :require => 'i18n/active_record'
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'globalize', github: 'globalize/globalize'

gem 'sunspot_rails'
gem 'globalize-accessors'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'slim-rails'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 4.4.0'
gem 'country_select'
gem 'friendly_id'
gem 'ckeditor'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'fog'
gem 'fog-aws'
gem 'devise'
gem 'devise_invitable'
gem 'pundit'
gem 'mail'
gem 'recaptcha', :require => 'recaptcha/rails'
gem 'roadie-rails', '~> 1.0'
gem 'sitemap_generator'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'dumper'

group :development do
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'sunspot_solr'
  gem 'progress_bar'
  gem 'letter_opener'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'mina'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'launchy'
end

group :test do
  gem 'poltergeist'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end
```

What gives here?

Comment: What happens if you run it with `bundle exec rails s`? Also, can you show us your `Gemfile`?

Comment: @Wikiti - Same result

Comment: Starting from the beginning of the manual the only issue could be in merging during `rails app:update`. Silly to ask, but I assume `rails -v` and `ruby -v` are giving you the right versions? Any errors during rails version upgrade?

Comment: @gen Yes, I'm getting rail 5 and ruby 2.3 as I expected. There weren't any errors on the upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the two space characters in front of the word `self`. You need to delete those two chars, and then just type them again.

There are some chars that are invisible in UTF-8, and it seems a few of them get included when copy-pasting from the Rails Guide.